# Вызов метода __init__ при множественном наследовании

Tags: python, python-3.x, наследование, множественное-наследование

Изучаю множественное наследование. Не понимаю, почему в одном случае вызывается метод init обоих родителей, а в другом - только первого родителя.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base")


class Base1(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("base1")


class Base2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("base2")


class Child(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        print("child")
        super().__init__()


child = Child()
print(Child.mro())
```

Получаю результат:

```
child
base1
[<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Base1'>, <class '__main__.Base2'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>]
То есть, вызывается init только для Base1.
```

Но если добавить вызовы init класса Base с помощью super():

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base")


class Base1(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("base1")
        super().__init__()


class Base2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("base2")
        super().__init__()


class Child(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        print("child")
        super().__init__()


child = Child()
print(Child.mro())
```

Получим другой результат, init будет вызван для Base1 и для Base2.

```
child
base1
base2
base
[<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Base1'>, <class '__main__.Base2'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Вот еще один пример(уберем класс Base):

```
class Base1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base1")


class Base2:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base2")


class Child(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        print("child")
        super().__init__()


child = Child()
print(Child.mro())
```

И снова сработает только один init

```
child
base1
[<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.Base1'>, <class '__main__.Base2'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Поясните пожалуйста, почему в одном случае срабатывает только один init, а в другом все возможные init. Заранее благодарен за пояснения.

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что `super().__init__()` - вызывает `__init__` родителя. Погружение в стек вызовов останавливается, когда нет явного вызова родительской функции, т.е. `super().__init__()`.

В вашем примере 1:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base")


class Base1(Base):
    def __init__(self):  # 2. Получил управление от Child.__init__
        print("base1")
        # 3. Вернул управление Child.__init__


class Base2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print("base2")


class Child(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):  # 0. Начало создания объекта.
        print("child")
        super().__init__() # 1. Вызвать родителя Base1.__init__
        # 4. Получил управление от Base1.__init__
        # 5. Создание объекта завершено.
```

Пример 2:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):  # 6. Получил управление от Base2.__init__
        print("base")
        # 7. Вернул управление Base2.__init__


class Base1(Base):
    def __init__(self):  # 2. Получил управление от Child.__init__
        print("base1")
        super().__init__() # 3. Вызвать родителя Base2.__init__
        # 9. Вернул управление Child.__init__


class Base2(Base):
    def __init__(self):  # 4. Получил управление от Base1.__init__
        print("base2")
        super().__init__()  # 5. Вызвать родителя Base.__init__
        # 8. Вернул управление Base1.__init__


class Child(Base1, Base2):
    def __init__(self):  # 0. Начало создания объекта.
        print("child")
        super().__init__() # 1. Вызвать родителя Base1.__init__
        # 10. Получил управление от Base1.__init__
        # 11. Создание объекта завершено.
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что во втором примере у вас в каждом классе есть `super().__init__()`

Поэтому каждый `__init__` будет по цепочке вызывать `__init__` следующего класса